# What should I do with my car after driving into water?

Tags: engine, water, hydrolock

So my car drove into water, and it stopped working at some point.  I then stopped my car, and me and a couple other people fished out the car.  We were able to start and drive the car after and I dried out most of the car after it went into deep water.  However, the car can only drive up to 20-25 mph, and it sputters even though it starts normally and can drive, and we were even able to drive it home at some point.  Does this mean the car is hydrolocked and will it likely be totalled?

Comment: Did the engine ingest water?  That's the biggest question in my mind.  If so, it's likely going to need a new engine.

Comment: Salt water is dramatically more corrosive . That is especially bad on all electrics, If anything with a circuit board was in salt water ,it is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

If you had hydrolocked your engine, then you wouldn’t be able to turn the engine over and the cylinder would still be full of water since it can’t escape from a compression stroke.

Check the air filter.  If you have pulled water into the air intake, the paper air filter may have disintegrated and almost totally blocked the air intake.  If it has remove all of it and see if it runs better then.

If this is a petrol/gas engine, the there will usually be a MAF sensor just after the air filter.  They often have a metal gauze located in front of the sensor.  The gauze could be totally covered with the filter paper.

As @jupiter says below, make sure you check your engine oil and transmission oil for water contamination.

Comment: Check all fluids. Water in oil or transmission fluid can be lethal.